# Closed or approximate formula for a finite product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, products

I have a product of the form:
$$ \frac{n}{n+a} \frac{mn-n}{m(n+a)-n} \frac{mn-2n}{m(n+a)-2n} \cdots \frac{mn-kn}{m(n+a)-kn}, $$
that is, 
$$ \prod_{i=0}^k \frac{mn-in}{m(n+a)-in}, $$
and I would like to know if there is a closed formula for it, or else an approximate formula. We may consider $m, n, a$ as constants, and it could be useful to know that $k << n$ and $k << m$.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are right, the word "asymptotic" is not very accurate here. I have replaced it by "approximate".

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle\prod\limits_{i=0}^k\frac{mn-in}{m(n+a)-in} = \frac{\prod\limits_{i=0}^k (m-i)}{ \prod\limits_{i=0}^k (m(1+a/n)-i) } = \frac{m!\,\Gamma(m(1+a/n)-k)}{(m-k-1)!\,\Gamma(m(1+a/n)+1)}$

$m!$ and $\Gamma(x)$ can be approximated by the [Stirling formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: That looks nice. Thanks !

Comment: You are welcome! ;)